# Too large number of skipped frames. FFMPEG, C program

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm writing program on C to capture RTSP stream and write it to files.
But after some time i get errors:

```
Too large number of skipped frames xxxx > 60000
```

After this files become incorrect and very small size. 
What the reason of it and how can o fix this problems?

a piece of code, where i capture frames and put them to buffer.

```
        ofmt = av_guess_format( NULL, sFileOutput, NULL );
        ofcx = avformat_alloc_context();
        ofcx->oformat = ofmt;
        int ret2=avio_open( &ofcx->pb, sFileOutput, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if(ret2<0){
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError occurred when opening output file: %s\n",av_err2str(ret2));
        }

        ost = avformat_new_stream( ofcx, NULL );
        avcodec_copy_context( ost->codec, iccx );

        ost->sample_aspect_ratio.num = iccx->sample_aspect_ratio.num;
        ost->sample_aspect_ratio.den = iccx->sample_aspect_ratio.den;

        ost->r_frame_rate = ist->r_frame_rate;
        ost->avg_frame_rate = ost->r_frame_rate;
        ost->time_base = av_inv_q( ost->r_frame_rate );
        ost->codec->time_base = ost->time_base;
        ost->codec->width = 1280;
        ost->codec->height = 800;

        av_init_packet( &pkt );

        while ( av_read_frame( ifcx, &pkt ) >= 0 && start_flag==0 && stop_flag==0){
            if ( pkt.stream_index == i_index ) {
                pkt.stream_index = ost->id;
                pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, ist->time_base, ost->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, ist->time_base, ost->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, ist->time_base, ost->time_base);
                pkt.pos = -1;
                av_copy_packet(&pkt_arr[pkg_index],&pkt);
            }
            av_free_packet( &pkt );
            av_init_packet( &pkt );
            pkg_index++;

            if(pkg_index>=bufer_size){
                pkg_index=pkg_index-bufer_size;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've given us almost nothing to work with. Typically we ask that you provide a short piece of code (and I suppose in this case perhaps an input) which replicates this issue.

Comment: i updated post, please check my code.